# Capybara Element is not clickable at point

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I was trying to use `capybara` to help me upload vocabulary to [memrise.com](http://memrise.com), but I encounter some problems in its login page.

Here is what I've written.

```
def sign_in
  self.visit 'https://www.memrise.com/login/'
  find(".inpt-large[name='username']").set 'my-username' # Step 1
  find(".inpt-large[name='password']").set 'my-password' # Step 2
  find('input.btn-success.btn-large').click              # Step 3
end
```

It can finish the `step1` and `setp2` but fail at `step3` sometimes.

And below is the error message.

```
gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok': Element is not clickable at point (592.5, 23). Other element would receive the click: <span class="nav-item-btn-text"></span> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

Comment: Show the HTML section from the page

Comment: The whole `html` is too many lines. Therefore, I've edited my code, I add the login link which `capybara` should visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only items on the page I can find matching <span class="nav-item-btn-text"></span> are in the fixed header, I'm guessing you're running your tests with too small of a window size, so the actual Login button you want to hit is off the page when the test is run.  This means when the test goes to click the button, it needs to scroll the item into view and it does that by scrolling it to the top of the page.  That leaves the button behind the fixed header and unable to be clicked.  To fix that you can either

1. increase your window size so the form doesn't need to be scrolled
2. set the `elementScrollBehavior` capability to `1` in your driver registration which will cause elements to be scrolled until they're visible at the bottom of the page rather than top.
3. scroll the page yourself before clicking the button

Additionally is there are reason you're using find(...).set vs just using fill_in for this form?

```
def sign_in
  visit 'https://www.memrise.com/login/'
  within('form#login') do
    fill_in('username', with: 'my-username')
    fill_in('password', with: 'my-password')
    click_button('Login')
  end
  assert_text('You are now logged in') # whatever messagge is shown once login complete
end
```

Comment: It seems fix my problem. Thanks.